# Getting Directions From an Annotation on the Map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cloudkit, mkannotation

I am trying to get directions from any annotations that are found on my map. I am using `CloudKit` as a database to store all my user's information. The annotations use the `location` index in `CloudKit` to map out their location on the map. Every time I run my code the annotation comes back as nil, how do I get my code to recognize the location from the annotation and return directions from apple maps?

```
@IBAction func getDirections(_ sender: Any) {

    let view = MKPointAnnotation().coordinate


    print("Annotation: \(String(describing: view ))")

    let currentLocMapItem = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()

    let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: view, addressDictionary: nil)
    let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)

    let mapItems = [selectedMapItem, currentLocMapItem]

    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

    MKMapItem.openMaps(with: mapItems, launchOptions:launchOptions)



}
```

Comment: You’re doing `let view = MKPointAnnotation().coordinate`. That still doesn’t make sense. You’re creating a blank annotation, and grabbing it’s coordinate (but it doesn’t have one). You should just get your coordinate (from iCloud or whatever) and use that coordinate directly when creating the `MKMapItem`.

Comment: Found it out! but now not all of my annotation will show... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745464/not-all-annotations-will-load-to-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You can use [`MKDirections`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections) to get directions right in your app, without ever going to the Maps app.
2. You can also pass it off to the Maps app (like your above example) so that the user can then enjoy the full real-time navigation (see traffic, etc.).

But you don’t use the “open in Maps” API to return directions within your app. Use `MKDirections` for that.

---

In your code snippet, you are doing:

```
let view = MKAnnotationView()
```

That creates an blank annotation view (with no annotation), so obviously if you try to get the annotation for it, it doesn't have one. You presumably want to either

- save the original annotation that you added to your map view and use that;
- respond to one of the `MKMapViewDelegate` methods and use the `annotation` for that annotation view on your map view; or
- go back to your original data source from which you originally created the annotation and create a new annotation (not annotation view) from that.

But don't try to create a new, blank annotation view and try to retrieve the annotation view for it, because it won't have one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob! I think i'm going to go with the second option (makes more sense for my app). My annotations are still being read as nil though, any thoughts on whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Your `let view = MKAnnotationView()` isn't doing what I think you think it's doing. That creates a new, blank annotation view that has no annotation associated with it. You either want to get the annotation view for one on your map view or save the annotation that you added to the map view and use that. See expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explained answer Rob! I'm working on it rn, thanks again.

Comment: This is what my code looks like now. Launching Apple maps works but its still not reading the info from Cloudkit...any suggestions?

Comment: That should be posted as a completely separate question, as it has nothing to do the above question re directions. When you post that, show how you saved it in iCloud, because that will dictate how to retrieve that.